# What is the return value of quote block?

Tags: elixir

I try to learn macros and have following code snippet:

```
defmodule ControlFlow do

  defmacro unless(expression, do: block) do
    quote do
      if !unquote(expression), do: unquote(block)
    end
  end

end
```

And it works as expected:

```
iex(16)> ControlFlow.unless 2 == 5, do: "block entered"
"block entered"
```

Now my question is, what is the return value of quote block?
This?

```
if !false, do: "block entered"
```

Comment: Downvote--basically zero research effort. Surely the same source that you found that example in covered Macro.to_string/1 as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Macro.to_string/1` and `IO.puts/1` in the macro to inspect what exactly is being returned:

```
defmodule ControlFlow do
  defmacro unless(expression, do: block) do
    ast = quote do
      if !unquote(expression), do: unquote(block)
    end
    ast |> Macro.to_string |> IO.puts
    ast
  end
end
```

Demo:

```
iex(1)> require ControlFlow
nil
iex(2)> ControlFlow.unless 2 == 5, do: "block entered"
if(!(2 == 5)) do
  "block entered"
end
"block entered"
```

So, your code turns into:

```
if(!(2 == 5)) do
  "block entered"
end
```